# I get different results in excel and mssql about difference in hours between two particular date

Tags: excel, date, difference

I have two particular days in DB and I want to calculate the difference in hours of this two days.This is the sample; stardate = 01.06.2018 02:00:51 and 
finisdate = 01.06.2018 03:37:00 and in MSSQL I used this query

```
CAST(  ROUND(CAST(BitisTarihi-BaslangicTarihi as float)*24,5,0)   as numeric(18,5))
```

Mssql give me this result : 1,60250 but When I use excel to calculate the difference ı get this result : 1,60248 .

Why ı get different results.This important for me because I get mssql query result by excel.When someone checks the result they see the difference,

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact, either in SQL Server or in Excel, and it's totally possible that the combined error between the two could result in this small discrepancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you're doing the round in Excel before multiplying by 24?

This gives me 1.6025

```
=(A1-B1)*24
```

This gives me 1.60248

```
=ROUND(A1-B1,5)*24
```

Answer (score 0):

" to calculate the difference in hours of this two days" <-- if you really just need to extract the hours from excel, the use of `hour()` and `date()` will be sufficient. (: